# Tensorflow-Lite - Benchmark tool - Varying results

Tags: android, performance, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to use the [TFLite Benchmark tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/tools/benchmark#on-android) with mobilenet model and checking the final `inference time` in microseconds to compare different models. The issue I am facing is with varying results between runs. I also found this section in the documentation which is pertaining to [reducing variance between runs on Android](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/tools/benchmark#reducing-variance-between-runs-on-android). It explains how one can set the CPU affinity before running the benchmark to get consistent results between runs. Currently using Redmi Note 4 and One Plus for the work.

1. Please, can someone explain what should I set the `CPU affinity` value as for my experiments?
2. Can I find the affinity masks for different mobiles online or on the Android phone?
3. When I increase the number of `--warmup_runs` parameter I get less varying results. Are there more ways in which I can make my results more consistent?
4. Are the background processes on the Android phone affecting my the `inference time` and is there a way I can stop them to reduce the variance in results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As the docs suggest, any value is fine, as long as you stay consistent with one across experiments. The one thing to consider is whether to use a big core or a little core (if you're a big.little architecture) and usually it's good to try both (they have varying cache sizes, etc.)
2. Yes you can typically find this information online. See http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0515b/CJHBGEBA.html as an example. You'll want to look at your particular phone, see the particular CPU it uses, and then google for more info from there.
3. I've tried --warmup_runs = 2000+ and typically it's pretty stable. There's a bit more variance with smaller models. For intensive models (at least for the particular device), you might want to see if the devices are overheating, etc. I haven't seen this for mid-tier phones, but heard that people sometimes keep their devices in a cool area (fan, fridge) for this.
4. They may, but it's unavoidable. The best you can do is close all applications and disconnect from the internet. I personally haven't seen them introduce too much variance though.